# how to store the roAssociativeArray of channels in brightscript?

Tags: roku, brightscript

**This is the function to store the list of favorites channels.But i'm not able to store the array in the registry as can only have string as input**

```
 Function addToFavorites(channeljson as object)as boolean
        print "started"
        sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "FuturV1")
        poster = CreateObject("roAssociativeArray")
        'if not sec.Exists("FavoriteChannels")
        contentList = CreateObject("roArray", 100, true)
        'else

        'end if 
       poster.ShortDescriptionLine1 = channeljson.name
       poster.SDPosterURL = channeljson.logo
       poster.HDPosterURL = ch`enter code here`anneljson.logo
       poster.url= channeljson.ch
       contentList.push( poster ) `enter code here`
       'sec.Write("FavoriteChannels", ba.ToAsciiString())

       print "again"
       print contentList.GetEntry(0) 
    end function
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to use **formatJSON() / parseJSON()**.

Answer (score 2):

Here an example of functions to save registry settings using ParseJSON and FormatJSON:

```
Sub SaveSettings(settings as Object)
    SaveRegistryString("Settings", FormatJSON({settings: settings}, 1))
End Sub

Function LoadSettings() as Dynamic
    json = GetRegistryString("Settings")
    if json <> ""
        obj = ParseJSON(json)
        if obj <> invalid
            return obj.settings
        end if
    end if
    return invalid
End Function

Function GetRegistryString(key as String, default = "") As String
    sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "YourAppName")
    if sec.Exists(key)
        return sec.Read(key)
    end if
    return default
End Function

Sub SaveRegistryString(key As String, value As String)
    sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "YourAppName")
    sec.Write(key, value)
    sec.Flush()
End Sub
```

Comment: I wish more Roku answers came with working examples such as yours.

Answer (score 1):

To Store any object into persistent Storage -

1. Convert the Object (roArray or roAssociativeArray) into String
2. Store that string in persistent storage.

---

To Retrieve the data from persistence storage -

1. Read the string from persistence.
2. Convert the String into Object to use. You can use ParseJSON function in case of roAssociativeArray.